# How to copy odd files in a folder where all the files are named using numbers

Tags: command-line, 18.10

I have folder A in which all the files (JPEG) are named using numbers (1,2,3....). Now I have to copy only the odd file names to another folder B. How to do this using terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
cp *[13579].JPEG ../some/other/dir
```

This will copy all files in current directory that haves an uneven number followed by .JPEG in the end, to the destination ../some/other/dir

Comment: I am getting an error "no such file or directory"

Comment: @VijayKumarS what command are you writing exactly ? You will have to change `../some/other/dir`to you chosen destination directory - which must exist and you must have write access to it..Also you have to be in the directory you want to copy from.

Comment: `cp /home/antman/Crowd_estimation/KK_JUNCTION/frames/*[13579].JPEG ../home/antman/Crowd_estimation/BN_KOVIL/BN_KOVIL_completed/odd`. This is the code I have pasted in the terminal. but this didnt work. I also tried opened terminal in the particluar folder where all the files are located. After that I tried your code `cp *[13579].JPEG ../home/antman/Crowd_estimation/BN_KOVIL/BN_KOVIL_completed/odd`

Comment: The total number of files in the folder is 133. I wanted to separate them into odd and even files and place it in the another folder

Comment: Can you give the output of the `pwd` command ?

Comment: `/home/antman` this is the output of the pwd -P command

Comment: @VijayKumarS that looks alright. Lets verify the source and destination of the copy:  What is the output of `ls /home/antman/Crowd_estimation/KK_JUNCTION/frames/*[13579].JPEG` - this should list all the odd jpeg files. And `ls ../home/antman/Crowd_estimation/BN_KOVIL/BN_KOVIL_completed/odd`- this should list the content of the destination directory. If any of those fails you have to work out what files or directories are missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118684/discussion-between-vijay-kumar-s-and-soren-a).